# Object tracking on a custom dataset

Tags: object-detection, yolo, yolov5, object-tracking

I'm new on computer vision field , I work on a project to detect and track trashs.
I use YOLO v5 to detect objects now I want to count each object that is present on the Video . I want some suggestion if there are some models that we can use on my own dataset.

Comment: recommendation are off-topic. please review [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

This repo contains all you need for tracking and counting objects: https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_StrongSORT_OSNet. If you already have a set of weights you could start tracking by:

```
 python track.py --yolo-weights /path/to/your/weights.pt
```

Adding the counting functionality should be straight forward

Comment: thank you, it work for me but results not good it count 100 time the same object , How I can I perform the result thanks in advance